# libGDX FreeType with HTML

Tags: android, libgdx, freetype

I'm using FreeType to to generate a font for me. I'm aware that this does not work for HTML, but is there a way to keep the same code base and use FreeType for platforms that can support it but still be able to deploy to HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I like the simple way :-). Declare a public static boolean isHtml = false; in your main class, then from your HTMLLauncher class set it to true. Now before running the FreeType code, ask if (!isHtml) {... Happy days :-)

Comment: How do I tell the GWT Compiler to not try and compile the freetype code though?

Comment: If you have FreeType declared as a dependency in build.gradle (Project : projectname) under project(":core") {, you need to exclude it under project(":html"). If you need it, an exact guide is here: [link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies)